# Why i can't install something on termux android?

Tags: android, termux

Its still get error, error and error again, i trying to install it again but still error

The error:

```
    CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/apt/methods/https": library "libssl.so.1.1" not found: needed by /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/libcurl.so in namespace (default)
E: Method https has died unexpectedly!            
E: Sub-process https returned an error code (1)
E: Method /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/apt/methods/https did not start correctly
```

Answer (score 1):

a temporary solution

```bash
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/openssl-1.1
```

Comment: Didn't work, rhe path doesn't exist